# ¿Al actualizar la versión de IOS cambia el id del Iphone?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Utilizo este código para obtener el id del Iphone:

```
let datosTelefono = UIDevice.current
let idTelefono = datosTelefono.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
```

Esta funcón me devuelve algo similar a esto: `8B8874CD-4F94-43A6-92BE-CA3B3C531944`

Mi pregunta es: si actualizo la versión de `IOS` del Iphone, cambia ese valor?

Comment: Yo creo que no, ese uuid es único de tu teléfono. Se te ha cambiado?

Comment: Pues no estoy seguro porque lo almaceno codificado en `md5`, pero diria que si @Spidvmp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hace mucho tiempo Apple prohibió el uso del `UDID` y se pasó a utilizar el `UUID`. 
En tu caso, estás utilizando el correcto, pero has de saber que cambia en caso de borrar la aplicación o reinstalación de la misma y es único por cada aplicación (cada aplicación tiene un `UUID` distinto)
Por último, si utilizas el `UDID` Apple te rechazará la aplicación...

Comment: No, ya que el objetivo es evitar el tracking del usuario. Aún así, con el `UUID` puedes hacerlo igual, simplemente que tendrás que tener en cuenta más escenarios. Te recomiendo este artículo: http://blog.appsfire.com/udid-is-dead-openudid-is-deprecated-long-live-advertisingidentifier/

Comment: Perfecto, gracias